# Django. IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: MyApp_song.albums_id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

For starters, I just started learning Django.

I'm trying to add a new song object to my album via the form. But I don't want to manually select the album (my foreign key) that I want to add a new song to. Instead, I want the value of my foreign key to be set depending on the album I'm adding a new song from. In addition, I do not want to see the foreign key field on my form at all. How can i do that in Django?

I tried to do it like this:

**views.py**

```
class SongCreate(CreateView):
template_name = 'music/album_form.html'

# fields = ['albums', 'file_type', 'song_title', 'audiotrack', 'is_favorite']

model = Song
fields = ['file_type', 'song_title', 'audiotrack', 'is_favorite']

def form_valid(self, form):
    album = get_object_or_404(Album, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])

    form.instance.album = album
    return super(SongCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

**urls.py**

```
path('music/album/<int:pk>/add', views.SongCreate.as_view(), name='song-add'),
```

**models.py**

```
class Song(models.Model):
albums = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
file_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
song_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
audiotrack = models.FileField(upload_to='media/')
is_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('param', kwargs={'pk': self.albums.id})

def __str__(self):
    return self.song_title
```

**Link to add a new album**

```
                        <a href="{% url 'song-add' album.id %}">Add album</a>
```

But for some reason it doesn't work, although I thought it should help. So i'm getting this error.
Maybe you know what's the problem?

Thanks, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You named your `ForeignKey` `albums`, not `album`, hence `form.instance.album` does not set the value for the `ForeignKey`.

Comment: Thank you, I was just inattentive from fatigue, and did not notice the error. I appreciate your help. Take care!